# SQL order by and insert to each row position number

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to have select query with order by and as a result insert new column with position of each row ?

for example I have table:

```
Name
-------
A
D
D
B
C
B
```

and as a result I would like to have table:

```
Name Position
-------------
A 1
D 4
D 4
B 2
B 2
C 3
```

thanks for any help

Comment: what is the relation between 'A' and '1' - and 'B' and '2' - I am assuming you will order by Name?

Comment: You edited two minutes ago, stating that if there is 'B' twice, then they should be assigned the same position value?

Comment: Are you talking about adding a column to the table itself or to your `select` query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [DENSE_RANK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825.aspx)

```
SELECT Name ,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Name) AS 'Position'
    FROM Table
```

This will produce

```
Name Position
-------------
A   1
B   2
B   2
C   3
D   4
D   4
```

so it may be difficult to maintain the original ordering

Comment: Looks like you need `dense_rank`

Answer (score 1):

use row_number

```
SELECT name,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY name) as Position
 FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    Name, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Name) AS POSITION 
FROM Table_1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Name, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Name) AS 'Position' 
FROM Table
```